# automatically use const-ref by big parameters

Tags: c++, templates, const-reference

When I have following pseudo-class:

```
template <class T> class tmplClass
{
    void doSomething(T input);
};
```

Is there a way to change `void doSomething(T input)` to `void doSomething(const T& input)` when sizeof(T) is larger the the system architecture.

Means, when you have `tmplClass<char> c;` for example, use `void doSomething(T input)` and when you have `tmplClass<[another big class with lots of variables]>` use `void doSomething(const T& input)`

1. Do I get any optimization out of this?
2. Is there anything I have to do, or can gcc do this automatically
3. If I have to do something, what?

Comment: It's not a pseudo-class. It's called a *template*.

Comment: Take a look at [Boost.CallTraits](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/call_traits.htm).

Comment: @KerrekSB I know... but what I wanted to say with pseodo-class, is that this actually is just an example ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure:

```
template<typename T, bool=true>
struct eff_arg {
  typedef T type;
};
template<typename T>
struct eff_arg<T, (sizeof(T)>sizeof(int))> {
  typedef T const& type;
};
// C++11 addition

template<typename T>
using EffArg = typename eff_arg<T>::type;
```

use:

```
template <class T> class tmplClass
{
  // C++11
  void doSomething(EffArg<T> input);
  // C++03
  void doSomething(typename eff_arg<T>::type input);
};
```

and replace `sizeof(int)` with whatever type you want to use as the "point where you want to pass as a reference instead of by value".

Note that the size of a parameter is a mediocre way to make this decision: An extremely small class (even smaller than a pointer!) could have deep copy semantics where a large structure is duplicated when it is duplicated.  And often the cut-off shouldn't be size of `int` or a pointer but bigger than that, because indirection has a cost.

An idea might be to copy only objects that don't manage resources and are sufficiently small.  `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value && (sizeof(T) <= 2*sizeof(void*))` might be the kind of check you should make before passing a `T` rather than a `T const&` when you have no need for a copy of the data.

This leads to the following:

```
template<typename T, bool=true>
struct eff_arg {
  typedef T const& type;
};
template<typename T>
struct eff_arg<T,
  std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value
  && (sizeof(T)<=2*sizeof(void*))
> {
  typedef T type;
};
template<typename T>
using EffArg = typename eff_arg<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, easy:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void do_something(typename std::conditional<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(void *)),
                                                 T const &, T>::type x)
    {
        // ... use "x"
    }

    // ...
};
```

You might want to assign the resulting type to some type alias for easy reuse.

As @Yakk suggests, it might be good to also add `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value` to the condition to avoid accidentally copying something that's expensive to copy or that might throw.

Comment: Type alias in C++11: `template<typename T> using EffArg = typename std::conditional< (sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*)), T const&, T>::type`, then use `EffArg<T>` as your "could be `T`, could be `T const&`, depending on how big `T` is" type.

Comment: Not bad too, but I think this would lead to pretty big (and unreadable) header files